# Is there a difference between the terms "strobe" and "pulse"?

Tags: digital-logic

What’s the correct term in digital design for a 1 bit signal which goes high for one clock cycle and then low again? I’ve seen both “strobe” and “pulse” being used.

I’m from Austria. Austrian and German colleagues seem to prefer “strobe” while colleagues from the US and Israel usually say “pulse”.

Edit: Regarding the close votes: I’d be happy about a definition from a reputable source or even just an answer from someone who knows what they are talking about. Bonus points if the origin of either word is explained.

Comment: I suppose it depends on context and who is talking and what they are talking about. I've listened when both words were put together as in *"a strobe pulse."*. So which is that? A pulse or a strobe? Other phrases I can recall are "triggered strobe" (in the case where a trigger gated exactly one clock duration, some time later on) or "strobe clock signal." I personally don't use "pulse" that much. Sounds like I'm checking my heart and it's vague. But I'm just a hobbyist. I'll let the pros speak for themselves about that. Regardless, just make sure  the context is clear and the rest will follow.

Comment: A pulse is a self-contained description. A pulse becomes a strobe when (I suspect) it is used to do something like strobe or gate another signal. Pulse strikes me as being a noun whereas strobe strikes me as being more verb orientated.

Comment: These terminologies are all matter of opinion and context.

Comment: @MituRaj: In which context would you prefer which term?

Comment: I usually use the term pulse when it is not related to other signals and the term strobe when it is used to gate another signal or group of signals.

Answer (score 3):

IEEE Std. 181-2011 "IEEE Standard for Transitions, Pulses, and Related Waveforms" does not use the term "strobe" at all. It talks about pulse waveforms:

> pulse waveform: A waveform whose level departs from one state, attains
> another state, and ultimately returns to the original state.

Comment: In things such as DDRx memories, the term strobe is explicitly used. Numerous 'standards' merely ratify what has been historically used..

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of context, and any distinction will be subtle. I know of one instance where the word "strobe" is used deliberately instead of "pulse", because the word "pulse" does not convey the same sense, or spirit, of the intended purpose.

The [CA3140 opamp datasheet](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/ca3140-ca3140a-datasheet) labels one of the device's pins as "strobe". The voltage at this pin does not explicitly cause the output to change voltage, per se, rather it causes the output to be either enabled or disabled. By this I mean that the output can be as you would expect from any opamp, some analogue voltage, or can be disconnected entirely from the device's internals, to be "floating" free.

The strobe pin is always held at some known high or low voltage, and this voltage determines the enabled/disabled state (normal/floating) of the output. Technically, the difference is that the pin 8 voltage is a square "waveform", but the ouput pin 6 state is better described as "low or high impedance".

Thus, in the context of a voltage applied to the strobe pin (pin 8), and the effect this has on the output (pin 6), this phrase may help to clarify the distinction between the terms "strobe" and "pulse", as used in the datasheet:

> a low voltage *pulse* at pin 8 will cause the output to momentarily
> *strobe* on.

If that wasn't clear enough, try this:

> the "strobing" of the output of this device does not directly cause the
> output voltage to rise or fall, but rather to be imposed or not
> imposed. Constrast this with some ever-present high or low voltage
> at pin 8, whose transistions would be more aptly described
> as "pulsing".

Comment: @Michael: As I read this back, I realise it may seem condescending, because you proably know what "high impedance" and "floating" and all such terms mean. Please forgive me if that's the case!